# Redirect to login page after successful login at chatGPT openai

Tags: openai-api, chat-gpt-4

When ever I log into the openai.com I get an error in console and then get redirected to login page.

I've tried incognito mode and VPN services but it was not fixed

P.S I'm living in Iran right now.

Answer (score 2):

because of the restrictions and sanctions in Iran, people have trouble accessing the service even via VPN services.

What solved the issue was using [Shecan](https://shecan.ir) DNS services.
This made the login process proceed one more step and get stuck while trying to access an address that apparently [Shecan](https://shecan.ir) is not covering.

After that I believe the login was made successfully **but for using ChatGPT I needed to turn my VPN back on again.**

I hope this piece of advice makes your like a little easier :)